# Object-fit: cover; stretches the parent element

Tags: css

I'm creating a grid for a blog and I cropped the images with object-fill: cover; so that they look all the same, regardless of the image aspect ratio.
The problem is that as I do that, the portion of the image which is cropped stretches the parent element (a div) and moves the title which is under the relative photo.

Here's a simplified version of the code:

```html
<div class="parent">

      <img src="#" class="child" style="max-height: 190px; object-fit: cover;">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      
</div>
```

Is there a way of solving this with still using object-fit or should I use an alternative?

Thanks for your time

Edit:
Here's a picture of how it looks like.
[The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Izi3x.png)

Comment: Please edit your post and add an image where we can see the effect you are describing.

Comment: @cloned Added, thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest answer I have is to put your image as background :

```css
.parent {
  background-image: url("https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360");
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <h2>Title</h2>
</div>
```

Here, I've just removed the image from the html, and put it as bg in the css. You can tweak the properties of the bg, here I've for example used `background-position` to center the image.

Another solution is to put the position of your image as `absolute` :

```html
<div class="parent">

      <img src="#" class="child" style="max-height: 190px; object-fit: cover; position:absolute;">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      
</div>
```

Comment: Tried both, the first resulted in a bit strange formatting of the images, with some mirroring at the borders, the second did not change anything. Maybe with a little work on the first I can achieve the wanted results, I'll let you know. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Oh, what was missing ?